# Problem with list() function in PHP

Tags: php

I've written the code below:

```
$release_id = intval(filter_var($_GET["rid"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$query = "select * from press_releases where id = {$release_id}";

$result = $db->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

list($id, $short_description, $description, $created_date) = $row;

$db->close();
```

and I am using the variables such as `$description`, `$short_description` inside of the html tags but nothing shows. If I use the code below which is same except for the `list()` function:

```
$release_id = intval(filter_var($_GET["rid"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$query = "select * from press_releases where id = {$release_id}";

$result = $db->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$id = $row["id"];
$short_description = $row["short_description"];
$description = stripslashes(html_entity_decode($row["description"]));
$created_date = $row["created_date"];

$db->close();
```

it works perfectly. Basically `list()` function cannot assign the values coming from the `$row` array.

I don't understand why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe the `list()` function works with associative arrays.  Try fetching your query results normally (numerical indices) and see if that resolves the issue for you.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the PHP docs](http://php.net/list) for `list()`:

> `list()` only works on numerical arrays
>   and assumes the numerical indices
>   start at 0.

Comment: This makes sense now. It is already said on the documentation but I couldn't see it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Comment: @Braveyard: In addition, `list()` assigns the values in reverse order (see the warning further below).

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract) instead of [`list()`](http://php.net/list).

This is the one that's appropriate for associative results. And you shouldn't use it with `SELECT *` but a concrete list of `SELECT varname1,varname2,varname3` so you don't get unexpected local variables.

<sub>It's also possible to use `extract(array_intersect_key(..))` to get a filtered list of variables to be extracted, but that's overkill for database result sets that you can control anyway.</sub>

Comment: I really like this version as well.. Thanks a lot. `extract` and `array_values` would be great solutions...

Answer (score 2):

A rather easy solution to this is as follows:

```
list($id, $short_description, $description, $created_date) = array_values($row);
```

Or simply don't fetch as assoc, but as a normal array.

I must say I don't really recommend doing this. Since your SQL query is fetching with `*`, it will break very easily - Let's say for whatever reason one of the columns gets shuffled around so it appears at some other position in the table. Bam.

Assuming you were to define each column separately in your query, then it would be fine.

Comment: In addition, you have to reverse the list of variables because `list` assignes the values from right to left.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fetch_row` rather than `fetch_assoc`, [see the example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php). <s>Associative</s>Hash arrays have no well-defined element order!

Comment: @Felix: Sorry, I meant "hash containers". Of course ordered associative containers like C++'s `std::set` do have an order -- but the order is not that of insertion, rather than of key value. I'm not sure about PHP, but I thought that associative arrays were hash-based, like `std::unordered_map`...

Comment: Uhm, I don't know about C++. But in PHP there is actually only one type of array and the elements are ordered (insertion order), no matter whether the keys are numeric or strings.

Comment: @Felix: I see -- is this actually guaranteed? (What an expensive data structure that must be...) If it were, then the list construction should really work for those arrays, too.

Comment: Yes it is. And yes it should work, but apparently it does not, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `list()` expects a numerically indexed array.  Try using 
`$row = $result->fetch_row();` instead

Answer (score 1):

`list()` expects an indexed array, not an associative one. Try using `fetch_row()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) like this:

```
list($id, $short_description, $description, $created_date) = array_values($row);
```

Read the comment by kevin in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php#80910) on php.net.

Answer (score 1):

`list` does only work with numerically indexed arrays. Switch fetch_assoc to fetch_row or use array_values on $row before the assignment:

```
$row = $result->fetch_row();
```

or

```
list($id, $short_description, $description, $created_date) = array_values($row);
```